# how to install ndk(linux)?

Tags: android, installation, android-ndk

I am trying to download the Android NDK and then extract the files to a certain directory. How can I rename the NDK directory? Do I need to rename the directory?

How can I check and rename the directory?

Also, can I use the NDK in Eclipse? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, I have my directory named android-ndk under my home directory. 
I think it does not matter what the directory name is.

If its not already set, you need to set the environment variable as:

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/user/android-ndk

I have pasted following content from [android NDK page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html):

"Uncompress the NDK download package using tools available on your computer. When uncompressed, the NDK files are contained in a directory called android-ndk-version. You can rename the NDK directory if necessary and you can move it to any location on your computer."

You can always check the name of dir using following command from the place where you have uncompressed:

```
 ls -al android-ndk*
```

Then you can change the name to whatever you are comfortable by using `'mv'` command.

E.g. If current android ndk installation directory name is: android-ndk-r4b-linux-x86 and you need to change it to android-ndk , then use following command:

```
  mv  android-ndk-r4b-linux-x86  android-ndk
```

Comment: There are a few sample applications in the installation folder. You can refer those. Also you can go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html for more details. You can follow this URL for using NDK on eclipse: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html