# Android NDK - "Library not found" calling System.loadLibrary

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have successfully linked a native shared library for an Android app using ndk-build. To test a JNI call, I have a small app that simply calls one function from the library. I run/debug using Eclipse.

On one PC, under Windows and Cygwin, the library is loaded and the call succeeds. On another PC, under Ubuntu, the same app fails calling System.loadLibrary("...").

Given that it works on the first PC, the only differences between the two relate to the Eclipse workspace, search path settings in the OS, and the like.

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with Unix in general, so it may be just a matter of setting a search path for the shared library somewhere.

My library is certainly there. It's in libs/armeabi, also in obj/local/armeabi (don't know why, and interestingly it has a larger size there), and it's in the APK file.

Can anyone give me a hint? That would be most welcome.

P.S. I should add that on the Windows PC (where it works), in an attempt to debug the native code, I have applied changes to the Eclipse project like converting it to a mixed Jave/C++ project and configuring it to build the native library from within Eclipse. I don't know whether those project settings could be hurting the Ubuntu environment; just wanted to add the information. In any case, I debug the app as an Android (not C++) app.

---

Started from scratch using the HelloJNI sample and it works. There must have been something fundamentally wrong with my Eclipse project setup. So, in a way, it's solved :-)

Comment: I would look at this [answer][1] on Stack it will help setting up Linux


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758099/how-to-install-ndklinux

Comment: @JPM: That link applies to the installation folder of the NDK, not to the search location for one's shared library.

Comment: Since you don't know linux too well I would make sure you installed the NDK correctly and then build and run a test project to make sure.  Once that is done then you can build and test your project.

Comment: @JPM: Good suggestion; thanks. The HelloJni sample works fine, though. I'm wondering about why my lib is not found. Do you know what governs the search in Ubuntu/Eclipse/Android, and if there is a way to trace which locations are being searched?

Comment: The System.loadLibrary() call happens on the device, and has nothing to do with the library search path on the host. The only thing that could be different is in how Eclipse is building the apk - but without knowing more, I can't guess as to why it is possibly not working when you try to build the apk from ubuntu. I would start by comparing the apks produced when you build on windows vs.  on ubuntu.

Comment: Latest findings:

- Comparing the APK files shows equal structure but some differences in content, probably is due to different GCC versions on Windows/Ubuntu.

- Created Eclipse project from scratch on Ubuntu; didn't help.

- Discovered the APK created on Windows (works in the emulator) crashes on the actual device.

- The HelloJni sample works on the device under both Windows and Ubuntu. So I'll start again, working from there. Currently, my shared library consists of 15 static libraries I just ported from VC to GCC to use with Android. Maybe I'm not building the shared library correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog` should be missing in your `Android.mk` file. I tried this in my `Android.mk` file and it worked fine for me.